# Cannot await 'method group' IEnumerable

Tags: c#

I have this error which I can't find the solution. Basically, this C# code is in a Console project which consume a Web API method to retrieve all the employee records.

PrintOneEmployee method works but PrintEmployee method is not.

```
    static async Task PrintEmployee()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:63665/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            //GET Method
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/Employees");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                IEnumerable<Employee> employee = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Employee>();

                //for loop employee

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Internal server Error");
            }

        }
        Console.Read();
    }

    static async Task PrintOneEmployee()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:63665/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            //GET Method
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/Employees/5");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Employee employee = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Employee>();

                Console.WriteLine("Id:{0}\n", employee.EmployeeID);

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Internal server Error");
            }

        }
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this line:

> ```
> IEnumerable<Employee> employee = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Employee>();
> ```

You're missing a closing `>` character at the end of `ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Employee>>`

Comment: omg. thanks a lot :D